# Magento product details page is not working

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I installed magento 1.9 and now product is showing and category is showing. when i go to product detail page. this is showing only Product image. no product description etc.

How to fix this. please help

Comment: please provide full description with screenshot or url

Comment: you added description ?